# How do I use the OFFSET() function to return rows in a different tab?

Tags: excel, offset

There is an excel sheet.

**In TAB1** - there is the data  (thousands of rows and columns - names, birth date and the ID number)

**In TAB2** there is a drop down list (Data Validation) of the names. I used the MATCH() function to determine the position of the name
appearing in the dropdown.

Now I would like to use the offset function so that if a user selects a name, it displays that person's birth date and ID number in TAB2.

---

Hypothetical Example
-> TAB 1
Name: Anna Taylor | Birth Date: 08 June 1992 | ID: 116554234

->Tab 2
Drop down list - selected name = Anna Taylor
Now, I would like to use the offset function here to paste her Birth Date and ID number next to it.

//Note there are thousands of names.

Comment: Typically you'd use INDEX/MATCH for this: if the "name" column is left of the others you can just use VLOOKUP

Comment: and if there are thousands of names, there's a risk of duplicates: only the first birth date and id will be returned. Maybe add a countif warning if there are more than one match.